# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on payment section of in app purchases

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have a `UITableView` set up with different in app purchases. Each option takes you to a view controller which also has the delegate and what not to do the in app purchases. A plist file is change to determine which option in the table view was selected. This all works fine. I put in NSLogs to make sure the variable was getting set. However when i click buy, it only works half the time and the other half i get

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

on the line:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Everything is set up right as far as the in app purchases go because it used to work before i switched to this way of doing it. I think it may have something to do with calling the productsRequest because i set up `NSLog` in the `didReceiveResponse` delegate and it receive the response much quicker after the first time. Im stuck. The ones that dont work are always random, no rhyme or reason. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like memory management issue, or your static method default queue is not returning anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up NSZombieEnabled it will make anything that gets deallocated into an object that will log a message when and who called it.  This is quite useful for tracking down these types of EXC_BAD_ACCESS issues.

Answer (score 11):

I was having this problem and found that the issue was that I was releasing the transaction observer I'd added to the default SKPaymentQueue. Apparently SKPaymentQueue does not retain its observers, probably to prevent a retain cycle.

So, specifically, I changed this code:

```
- (void) setupAppStoreObserver {
    AppStoreObserver *appStoreObserver = [[AppStoreObserver alloc] init];   
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:appStoreObserver];
    [appStoreObserver release]; // This is the problem
}
```

To this:

```
- (void) setupAppStoreObserver {
    AppStoreObserver *appStoreObserver = [[AppStoreObserver alloc] init];   
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:appStoreObserver];

    // Note, we don't release the appStoreObserver because it is not
    // actually retained by SKPaymentQueue (probably to prevent retain cycles)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Note that your fix will fail when using ARC. I had to assign the observer to a global variable as a work around.

Comment: @emp I try to stay away from global variables. I made StoreObserver an instance variable of AppDelegate. As long as there is a reference to it the SKPaymentQueue is safe and the observer is hidden inside the AppDelegate class.

Comment: So...we don't release it at all? How strange!

Answer (score 10):

You need to remove observer:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: Geaka's answer is the opposite of benvolioT's solution. I prefer releasing the transaction observer and reallocating when needed rather than keeping it around as a potential memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

> MyStoreObserver *observer = [[MyStoreObserver alloc] init];

observer object is gone after called.
create member variable to store MyStoreObserver may be a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on addPayment  my solution was different ... and, in the end, easy.

Reading Ray Wenderlichs tutorial where he discusses an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, [see this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/page/24) he says, you get this error when you try to access a object that has been deallocated.

I was initializing MyStoreObserver where the ViewController did load.  I moved that to initWithNibName ... you know, right under where the template has typed 
// Custom initialization goes here.
The code I put there was

```
    MyStoreObserver *observer = [[MyStoreObserver alloc] init];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
```